# Testing Creation Variable Assignments in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

I'm creating a rspec test to see if the instance variable in the create method retains the data built. However, my test doesn't work since I'm returned with this error...

```
Failure/Error: assigns[:micropost]should eq(@post)
expected: #<Micropost id: 1, content: "Hello there", user_id: 1>
got: #<Micropost id: 2, content: "Hello there", user_id: 1>
```

My rspec test is

```
describe ::MicropostsController do

before :each do
  @post = FactoryGirl.create(:micropost)
end

it "tests the instance variable in create method" do
    post :create, micropost: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:micropost)
    assigns(:micropost).should eq(@post)
end
```

My FactoryGirl file is

```
FactoryGirl.define do

 factory :micropost do

  content "Hello there Bob!"
  user_id "1"
  #even if I got rid of the double quotations around 1, the stringify key error still 
  #pops up

 end

end
```

Here is the micropost controller create action code...

```
def create

@micropost = Micropost.new(params[:micropost])

 respond_to do |format|

  if @micropost.save

    format.html { redirect_to @micropost, notice: 'Micropost was successfully create.' 
    }

  else

    format.html { render action: "new" }

  end

 end

end
```

Comment: i've eddited my answer with your controller's code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to test that the micropost is created you have to pass some parameters to the post action, in your test you only build a new Micropost (in memory, not saved) and your create action doesn't even know that it exists:

I should do something like:

```
before(:each) do
  @micro_mock = mock(:micropost)
  @micro_mock.stub!(:save => true)
end

it "creates a micropost" do
  params = {:micropost => {:something => 'value', :something2 => 'value2'}}
  Micropost.should_receive(:new).with(params).and_return(@micro_mock)
  post :create, params
end

it "assigns the created micropost to an instance variable" do
  Micropost.stub!(:new => @micro_mock)
  post :create
  assigns(:micropost).should == @micro_mock
end
```

you should test the redirects and the flash messages to (stub the save method to true/false when needed)

Comment: Are mocks necessary? Couldn't I just stick with FactoryGirl?  I updated the code again. This time what I got and expected is the same except the id is off by 1.

Comment: You can use FactoryGirl, but your test will be slower, there will be a real object creation on a database which is not really needed (your controller doesn't really create the object, it only calls the Micropost's new method, you should test that). I had a lot of controller tests using FactoryGirl, then replaced everything for mocks and the tests takes less than half of time to run. Check this style guide for more info https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#rspec

Comment: your test is failing with the ID because you are creating an object on the before block and then creatin another object on the controller, then you have 2 different objects. you should at least stub the new method, Micropost.stub!(:new => @post) so you get exactly the same object, but again, since you stub the new method you doesn't need a Micropost object, you can use a mock there.

Comment: You've been incredibly helpful. Thanks for the time and patience with me. I will also check out the style guide you posted. Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting nil values in `micropost` because you have not posted any data in this line:

```
post '/microposts'
```

You need to actually include the data for this to work:

```
post '/microposts', :micropost => p
```

Comment: I'm returned with the following error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'stringify_keys' for "#<Micropost:4asdfsa23>":String`

Comment: What do you have in your micropost factory? It looks like you're returning a string...

Comment: Oh sorry, try switching `assigns[:micropost]` to `assigns(:micropost)`.

Comment: Are the attributes still `nil`? And can you post your controller code for the `create` action?

Comment: Posted the updated code and controller code in the question. The error is currently expecting the FactoryGirl micropost but got a micropost with all attributes as nil.